# Unable to see layout homepage in Zend MVC

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

when i added this code in bootstrap.php

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts');
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
        unset($view);
```

why do not show "hello world" in my home page?

application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml

```
<?php $this->doctype();?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->layout()->content; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

public/index.php

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL || E_STRICT);
// Identify the location of the application directory in respect to
// the bootstrap file's location, and configure PHP's include_path to
// include the library directory's location
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/'));
set_include_path(
APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
);
// Give the Zend Framework the ability to load classes on demand,
// as you request them, rather than having to deal with require() statements.
require_once "Zend/Loader.php";
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

// Retrieve the bootstrap.php file
try {
require '../application/bootstrap.php';
} catch (Exception $exception) {
printf("Could not locate bootstrap.php");
exit(1);
}
// Start using the front controller in order to route URL requests
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

application/bootstrap.php

```
 <?php
// Configure the site environment status.

defined('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT')
or define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
// Invoke the front controller
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
// Identify the location of the controller directory
$frontController->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');
// Create the env parameter so you can later access the environment
// status within the application.
$frontController->setParam('env', APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);
  // view and layout setup
  // Layout Configuration
Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts');
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
        unset($view);
  //      $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
//        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Language', 'en-US');
// Clean up allocated script resources
unset($frontController);
```

public/.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: what is that you are seeing in your homepage?

Comment: it is empty. my page is white. when i view source there are html tag but <body> /<body> do not include Hello World

Answer (score 0):

You don't **echo** your `$this->layout()->content;` segment in your layout.phtml. Try it.

Edit: I see you don't echo your doctype(), neither. As far as the core ZF is concerned, *nothing* gets printed, but *returned*. This way, *you* choose what to do with that value (print it, return it, store it, cache it, discard it etc.). I'll give your tendency a name: "wordpress expectation".